# how to edit a xsl file, so that it loads different templates, based on some checking?

Tags: xml, xslt, xsl-fo

I have two xsl file each for different type of machines

1. for various unix flavour machines
2. for various windows machines

I want to load another xsl based on checking the osname from these xsl

> eg: if osname="Windows" then load **windows.xsl**
>      else load **nix.xsl**

So in order to do that there should be another xsl that does the checking. So now how can I load these **windows** and **nix** xsl's based on osname checking?

for more detail I am giving xml for win and nix machines

1. nix machine xml

   `<machine>
     <system>
       <osname>Linux</osname>
       <username>Abhishek</username>
     </system>
   </machine>`
2. win machine xml

   `<machine>
      <system>
        <osinfo>
          <osinfo field='OS Name' information='Microsoft(R) Windows(R) Server 2003 Enterprise x64 Edition
   ' />
   <osinfo field='OS Version' information='5.2.3790 Service Pack 2 Build 3790
   ' />
   <osinfo field='OS Manufacturer' information='Microsoft Corporation
   ' />

   </osinfo>
   <username>Matt</username>
   </system>
   </machine>`

I am also providing the templates,

> **unix** xsl template

```
 <xsl:template name="unixsystem" match="machine">
    <span style="color:#328aa4"><a name="_systeminfo" href="#_top">System Info</a></span>

<table border="1" >
    <tbody>
    <tr>
    <th align="left">OS Name</th>
    <th align="left">User Name</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td><xsl:value-of select="system/osname"/></td>
    <td><xsl:value-of select="system/username"/></td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>

    </span>
</xsl:template>
```

> **Windows** xsl template

```
<xsl:template name="winsystem" match="machine">
        <span style="color:#328aa4"><a name="_ospatches" href="#_top">OS Information: </a></span></h2>

        <table border="1">
            <tbody>
            <tr>
                <th>Field</th>
                <th>Information</th>
            </tr>

            <xsl:for-each select="osinfo/osinfo">
                <tr>
                    <td valign="top" ><xsl:value-of select="@field"/></td>
                    <td valign="top" style="width: 2;"><xsl:value-of select="@information"/></td>
                </tr>
            </xsl:for-each>
            </tbody>
        </table>
        </xsl:template>
```

Instead of using `contains` can this work?

```
<xsl:choose>
  <xsl:when test="osinfo/osinfo/@information='Windows'">
    <xsl:call-template name="winsystem"/>
  </xsl:when>
  <xsl:otherwise>
   <xsl:call-template name="unixsystem"/>
  </xsl:otherwise>
</xsl:choose>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because `xsl:include` or `xsl:import` must be child of `xsl:stylesheet` you won't be able to manage them conditionally.

May be it's better if you include both stylsheets in your main one and then call the appropriate template based on your selection.

Example:

```
 <xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

  <xsl:include href="win.xsl"/>
  <xsl:include href="unix.xsl"/>

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:choose>
      <xsl:when test="contains(//osinfo/@information, 'Windows')">
       <xsl:call-template name="winsystem"/>
      </xsl:when>
      <xsl:otherwise>
       <xsl:call-template name="unixsystem"/>
      </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
  </xsl:template>

 </xsl:stylesheet>
```

Obviously this is just a suggestion and it's based on having two templates named win and unix on two different stylesheets named win.xsl and unix.xsl.

Hope this helps

---

Extended answer after seeing the templates

I would name the two templates in different way and remove `match`. I mean I would use:

**unix xsl**

```
<xsl:template name="unixsystem">
 <!-- your staff -->
</xsl:template>
```

**windows xsl**

```
<xsl:template name="winsystem">
 <!-- your staff -->
</xsl:template>
```

Afterward you can call the templates as indicated above. Note that I've removed `match`. In this way you should be able to call the templates. I've not investigated if the contents of your xsl files is correct. I've also corrected a miscode (an unclosed `xsl:choose`) in my xsl.

Comment: @empo: Thanks for your reply, from where `name="win"` is referring to itself?

Comment: @empo: I got it, the template names itself, I have 2 templates in each file, so I can use `<xsl:call-template` twice?

Comment: @empo: I get this warning and nothing happens after that `The attribute axis starting at an attribute node will never select anything` any ideas?

Comment: @Abhishek Simon: can you edit your question inserting some more information? You should edit your xsl files so that they are templates that can be called. Note: I'm not sure that `xsl:choose` test with `contains` is correct.

Comment: @Abhishek Simon: I mean, can you add to your question the code you want to call? or a part of it? It's hard to help you without that.

Comment: @empo: I added my templates for the 2 xsl's though need a little editing

Answer (score 1):

Generally if you want two variants of a stylesheet, you should put the WIN part in WIN.xsl, the LIN part in LIN.xsl, and the common part in COMMON.xsl. Then WIN.xsl should import COMMON.xsl; LIN.xsl should import COMMON.xsl; and if you want the WIN variant you should nominate WIN.xsl as your top-level stylesheet, while if you want the LIN variant you should nominate LIN.xsl.

In other words, special-case code should import general-purpose code, not the other way around.